# SymPy: how to reduce the depth of replacement when printing out functions

Tags: sympy

I'm using [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) to perform some algebraic symbolic calculations. As part of the problem, I have a function that depends on another function, i.e.:

[image: r_o]

[image: f]

When I print out higher-order derivatives of `f(r_o)` I get very complicated expressions because `r_o` is always replaced by its explicit expression. I would like to reduce the amount of printout by keeping the symbol `r_o` instead of it being replaced. How do I control the "depth" of replacement during printout, while performing the full calculation ?

Here's a code example:

```
import numpy as np
import pytest
import sympy
from sympy import cse, cos, simplify, sin, sinh, tanh, sqrt, tensorcontraction, diff, Function, Piecewise, Symbol

sympy.init_printing()

syms = sympy.symbols("t x y z")
r_o = Function('r_o')(syms[0], syms[1], syms[2], syms[3])
f = Function("f")(r_o)
V, r_o, f
f.diff(syms[0])
```

[image]

I would like to see only `r_o` and not `r_o(t,x,y,z)`.

Thanks,
Riccardo

Comment: If you'd enter your equations as code, you'd highly increase your chances of obtaining a helpful answer.

Comment: Without any code on how you differentiate or anything else, it is very difficult to give any advice. But note, that when you define `f_r_0`, it becomes a new expression that knows nothing about `r_0`. You either need to use `subs` or `replace`.

Comment: Here's a working example:
```
import numpy as np
import pytest
import sympy
from sympy import cse, cos, simplify, sin, sinh, tanh, sqrt, tensorcontraction, diff, Function, Piecewise, Symbol

sympy.init_printing()

syms = sympy.symbols("t x y z")
r_o = Function('r_o')(syms[0], syms[1], syms[2], syms[3])
f = Function("f")(r_o)
V, r_o, f
f.diff(syms[0])
```

Comment: If it's only a visual thing you want, then, instead of `f.diff(syms[0])` you could do `f.diff(syms[0]).subs(r_o, sympy.symbols('r_o'))` whenever you print it.

Comment: Ah! That seems to have done the trick! Thx!